# Syntax error near "," with postgres go lib pq

Tags: sql, go

I try to create a simple insert statement and get the error:

> pq: syntax error at or near ","

```
txn, err := db.Begin()
stmt, err := db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO advertiser_per_day (id,advertiser_name,additional,customer_id,site_id,tracking,counter,day,month,year) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`)
```

If I put the statement into a query tool for postgres all works fine...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use (`$n`) instead of `?` for the bound parameters.

Comment: `?` is for mysql, `$n` works fine in my code. Are you sure parameters isn't empty ? Show the full code please.

Comment: thanks for you help. Not even getting to the place he fills the parameters.. it fails before...

Comment: i try to do this in the end: INSERT INTO advertiser_per_day (id, advertiser_name, additional, customer_id, site_id, tracking, counter, day, month, year) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET counter=counter+1 but now getting error pq: column reference "counter" is ambiguous
Do you have a last guess for me. Would be awesome

Comment: Looks like postgres dont recognize what column in wich table to use. you should denoted it like `advertiser_per_day.counter` or something like this.